# Why the "give" in “I don't give a flying f***”?

Tags: meaning, verbs, offensive-language, phrase-meaning, idiom-meaning

I’m not a native speaker. I know that *I don't give a flying fuck* means "I don’t care", but how did it come to mean that? Specifically, why does the verb *give* mean "don’t care" here?

Comment: Think about it this way: if you live in a place with a small almost worthless coin -- call it a penny -- what would you mean if you said "I would not give you a penny for this"? You would say you don't care for it. Same for "I don't give `X` for `Y`" -- you would not exchange even `X` (usually something fanciful, worthless, and obscene, as here) for `Y` (which is what is being dissed by the expression). The _give_ is the _give_ of _The sellers give the buyers the merchandise, after they have paid_.

Comment: I imagine there are plenty of folks in your social circle who could answer this for you in person. I doubt you needed to bring it to EL&U.

Comment: I disagree that this question is better suited for ELL. It's been asked here and should stay here.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your question is a misunderstanding of *give*. Give doesn't mean *don't care*. The *don't* is already in the phrase:

> I **don't** *give* a flying fuck.

[Give](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/give): to bestow, especially officially; confer.

I *don't give* means:

> I don't *bestow/confer/hand over/offer/impart*, etc.

What don't you give? Well, if you don't want to give anything of value, then you *don't give a damn*.

In the middle ages, there was a common saying *not worth a curse.* To damn someone is to curse someone to damnation. *Not give a damn* is to see something as unworthy of giving a curse **or care** over.

If you want to say it less emphatically, you can say

> I don't give a hoot.

If you want to be *more* emphatic, you can say

> I don't give a *flying fuck*.

Since a flying fuck is an imaginary thing to most people, this means you care so little that you wouldn't even give the thing something non-existent.

Basically, it means **I don't care**.

<sub>damn (v.) late 13c., "to condemn," from Old French damner "damn, condemn; convict, blame; injure," derivative of Latin **damnare** "to adjudge guilty; **to doom**; to condemn, blame, reject... the optative expletive use likely is as old. - Etymonline</sub>