# What is the origin of the phrase "to not give two f***s"?

Tags: american-english, offensive-language, african-american-vernacular-english

I was curious about the origin of the phrase "to give two fucks". When did the English language first feature counting to a number to express a level of vulgarity? And why two specifically?

For example of a modern usage, Drake famously rapped,

> I could give two fucks 'bout where the Grammys go

in ["Blessings"](https://youtu.be/M6t47RI4bns?t=123) (2015) by Big Sean.

Comment: It's just a play on "give a fuck" where the implied number is one; you would also hear "five" (attractive because of the alliteration) and basically any other number.

Comment: I think it is certainly a valid question about usage but you could have usefully researched such expressions in Google ngram and discussed your findings before posing it.

Comment: There's a question on the origin/meaning of "I don't give a fuck" here; two fucks is just a variant, as mentioned: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/178710/why-the-give-in-i-dont-give-a-flying-f